# Difference of the following snippets

Tags: c++, c

Please tell me what is the difference of

```
typedef struct Tcl_ObjType {
    char *name;
    Tcl_FreeInternalRepProc *freeIntRepProc;
    Tcl_DupInternalRepProc *dupIntRepProc;
    Tcl_UpdateStringProc *updateStringProc;
    Tcl_SetFromAnyProc *setFromAnyProc;
} Tcl_ObjType;
```

and

```
struct Tcl_ObjType {
    char *name;
    Tcl_FreeInternalRepProc *freeIntRepProc;
    Tcl_DupInternalRepProc *dupIntRepProc;
    Tcl_UpdateStringProc *updateStringProc;
    Tcl_SetFromAnyProc *setFromAnyProc;
};
```

I have see the first version here: http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TclLib/ObjectType.htm , and don't know why it is written as it is.

Comment: http://www.functionx.com/cpp/keywords/typedef.htm

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For **C++**, there is no difference.

If this was a **C** program and you used the first variant, you could do:

```
Tcl_ObjType instanceOfStructure;
```

instead of

```
struct Tcl_ObjType instanceOfStructure;
```

Comment: But in C for the second version I can't write Tcl_ObjType instanceOfStructure;???

Comment: @Narek no, you have to write `struct Tcl_ObjType instanceOfStructure;`. That's the catch.

Comment: See http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/c-vs-c++.html for more information on structs in C and C++.

Comment: Thanks for the last link. It was really useful.

Comment: Actually, I'm not sure that there is no difference in C++.  The second `Tcl_ObjType` hides the first, so `Tcl_ObjType` is a `typedef`ed symbol, not the actual name of the class.  (I can't think of a case where this would make a difference, however.)

Answer (score 1):

You've gave the structure a type definition (In layman terms, provided an alternate name to an existing type):

Using your first example, you can then use it to reference objects/declare new objects via:

```
Tcl_ObjType newObj;
```

Comment: As you can in the second example.  The first is a C'ism; in C, structure tags live in a namespace of their own, and are only visible after the keyword `struct`.  In C++, structure tags are introduced in the surrounding scope, just like any other symbol.